# Evaluating a formula with the variable changing each time

Tags: python

I am trying to evaluate an expression for 4 different values for on of my variables. I am trying do create a for loop using np.arange as my variable is a float.

```
import numpy as np
for Mf in np.arange(0.8,0.01,1.5):
    Vinf=Mf*(gamma*R*tatm)**0.5
    print(Mf)
```

I want to evaluate the above expression for Mf = 0.8, 0.9, 1.2 and 1.5. I simply don't know how to do this or using a for loop is even appropriate. Finally, I want to save the output Vinf in an array. How could I achieve all of this?

Edit:

Ok I got the above code working thanks to user gmds. I am trying to use the list created for Mf_values to be used in the expression for P0 in my code. I have tried it in the following way:

```
Mf_values=[0.8, 0.9, 1.2, 1.5]
Vinf_values=[Mf_value*(gamma*R*tatm)**0.5 for Mf_value in Mf_values]
print(Vinf_values)
P0=[(1+((gamma-1)/2)*(Mf_values**2)**(gamma/(gamma-1))]
print(P0)
T0=(1+((gamma-1)/2)*(Mf_values**2))*tatm
```

I want to use the 4 different Mf_values for solving the expression for P0 and T0 and save the results in a list in a similar fashion to Vinf_values. However, python gives me the following error:

```
    P0=[(1+((gamma-1)/2)*(Mf_values**2)**(gamma/(gamma-1))]
                                                      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

How do I solve this issue?

Comment: Is there anyone that could help me with the second piece of code?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `list` comprehension:

```
Mf_values = [0.8, 0.9, 1.2, 1.5]

Vinf_values = [Mf_value * (gamma * R * tatm) ** 0.5 for Mf_value in Mf_values]
```

Answer (score 0):

For this tiny example you don't need any `numpy`, You can do it in pure python like this:

```
Vinfs = []
for Mf in [0.8, 0.9, 1.2, 1.5]:
    Vinf=Mf*(gamma*R*tatm)**0.5
    Vinfs.append(Vinf)
Vinfs = np.array(Vinfs) # If you want to have `ndarray` as your output
```